# Drill down rss reader iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have made a simple rss reader. The app loads an xml atom file in an array.

Now I have added categories to my atom feed, which are first loaded in the array

What is the best way to add drill down functionality programmatically. 
Now only the categories are loaded into the array and displayed.

This is the implementation code

```
.....
loading xml file <snip>
.....

    - (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
        NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
        NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
        NSLog(@"error parsing XML: %@", errorString);

        UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
        //NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
        currentElement = [elementName copy];

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
            // clear out our story item caches...
            Categoryentry = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            currentID = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            currentContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

        //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
            // save values to an entry, then store that item into the array...
            [Categoryentry setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
            [Categoryentry setObject:currentID forKey:@"id"];
            [Categoryentry setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
            [Categoryentry setObject:currentContent forKey:@"content"];

            [categories addObject:[Categoryentry copy]];
            NSLog(@"adding category: %@", currentTitle);
        }
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
        //NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
        // save the characters for the current item...
        if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
            [currentTitle appendString:string];
        } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"id"]) {
            [currentID appendString:string];
        } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"summary"]) {
            [currentSummary appendString:string];
        } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"content"]) {
            [currentContent appendString:string];
        }
    }

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

        NSLog(@"all done!");
        NSLog(@"categories array has %d entries", [categories count]);
        [newsTable reloadData];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides a good sample app for demonstrating a drill-down tableview:

[SimpleDrillDown](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/index.html)

Comment: Thank you ver much.
That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Write a generic `UITableViewController` subclass that takes an array of values. Then, when the user taps on a row, get the array of posts associated with the selected category and pass that to a new view controller. Then, push the view controller onto the stack, using `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just released an open source [RSS/Atom Parser for iPhone](http://bit.ly/mwfeedparser) and hopefully it might be of some use.

I'd love to hear your thoughts on it too!